# Is there a Zkp pallet? or implementation?

Tags: pallet, zero-knowlage

I am looking for the application of ZKP protocols in Substrate.

By looking around I've found a project called [ZeroChain](https://github.com/LayerXcom/zero-chain) but it seems to be deprecated and no longer maintained.
Are there any Substrate projects or pallets **that enables me** using ZKP for protecting a user's privacy and sensitive data stored on chain?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Manta Network](https://www.manta.network/) and their Kusama counterpart [Calamari Network](https://calamari.network/).

Answer (score 1):

I think on-chain ZKP pallet is not so easy to provide, because the zkp algorithms is a trade-off between proof size and proof generation time, both of storage and calculation time is so expensive for on-chain transaction.

So, it's a good idea to try OCW.

You can also refer to [parami's ZKP feature](https://github.com/parami-protocol/parami-blockchain/pull/35), use OCW and IPFS to achieve feasibility.

Answer (score 1):

There is a WIP PR for arkworks-rs integration: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13031

You might want to check out https://github.com/achimcc/substrate-groth16 which verifyes a groth16 proof using arkworks library and this repo: https://github.com/achimcc/ark-substrate